# Update template variable using setAttribute/property

Tags: polymer

In my Polymer Element, I have a binding defined using the mustache syntax, e.g. `<input value="{{nick}}">`.

I would like to update the value of that input as well as the bound `nick` template variable using regular DOM operations, such as `nickInput.setAttribute("value", newVal)` or `nickInput.value = newVal` but neither works.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/warpech/nvbwqqqx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is Reflection.

Instead of defining your attribute as `nick: 'value'`, you will need to do it like this:

```
nick: {
  value: 'Paul',
  reflectToAttribute: true
},
```

By doing that you can now change the publicly available attribute. Any of the following 2 will work. You are not updating the model inside the input. You re updating the model of the custom element you created.

```
changeMe: function() {                
  this.nick = 'John'; 
  this.setAttribute("nick", 'Ringo');
}
```

More information here: [Attribute-reflection](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties#attribute-reflection)

Comment: Thanks for giving a hint! So this is a change since Polymer 0.5.0. Previously it was automatically reflected, as I recall